# Do statistical models allow for "ranking their outputs"?

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, estimation, ranks

Suppose you create a regression model that predicts the hourly salary based on age and height. Suppose you have some new age and height measurements for 5 new people. The regression model predicts the salary of these 5 new people, e.g. $20/hr, $15/hr, $0/hr, $40/hr, $100/hr. Does the statistical framework of regression models allow you to "statistically rank" these people?

Suppose the model was a good fit for the training data, can you say with statistical confidence that "it's likely the 5th person earns the most and the 3rd person earns the least"? Should this not be reasonable if the confidence intervals for each prediction don't overlap?  For instance, suppose these are the salary estimates for 3 people from a regression model:

[image]

In this case, are we allowed to conclude that the first person (i.e. left most) is expected to earn the most?

Or are there separate "ranking models" for these kinds of problems?

Comment: What makes this more complicated than knowing how to order 0, 15, 20, 40, and 100?

Comment: @ Dave: Thank you for your reply! I was just wondering: if the confidence intervals on each of the estimates overlap - the ranking might not be statistically significant?

Comment: You might be interested in [stochastic dominance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance), for which there are a few types.

Comment: @ Galen: Thank you for your reply! I am completely new to "stochastic dominance" - do you have any references and R implementations that you would recommend looking at? Thanks!

Comment: One solution is the [Tukey HSD](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=tukey+hsd).